# ToDoList: изменение состояния checkbox (перечерикивание текста)

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Делаю ToDo, не могу понять, как менять состояние чекбокса при включении или выключении галочки (т. е. поставили галочку - зачеркнулся текст) Что использовать CSS или только на JS? постановка задачи может звучит странно, но я новичок в этой теме) Прошу помочь)

Мой JS файл

```
window.onload = function () {
  var todoList = [];
  var stored = localStorage.getItem('todo');
  if (stored)
    todoList = JSON.parse(stored);
  out();

  document.getElementById('add').onclick = function () {
    var d = document.getElementById('in').value;

    var temp = {};
    temp.todo = d;
    temp.check = false;
    var i = todoList.length;
    todoList[i] = temp;
    console.log(todoList);
    out();
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todoList));
    localStorage.getItem('todo');

  }

  function createOnEnter(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
      document.getElementById('add').click();
  }

  window.addEventListener("keyup", createOnEnter);

  function out() {
    var out = '';
    for (var key in todoList) {
      if (todoList[key].check == true) {
        out += '<input type="checkbox" checked>';
      }
      else {
        out += '<input type="checkbox">';
      }
      out += todoList[key].todo + '<br>';

      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".valuetask").eq(index).addClass("valuetask2");
      } else {
        $(".valuetask").eq(index).removeClass("valuetask2");
      }


    }
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = out;

  }
}
```

Мой CSS

```
.valuetask2{
   text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Comment: Где ваша разметка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое решение на чистом CSS:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox">Чекбокс</label>
```

Comment: Уже понятней, но вопрос еще вот в чем, как мне привязать к новым пунктам, которые я добавляю через текстовое поле, т. е. они появляются с чекбоксом но эта функция с ними не работает

Comment: @Moran ваш код не работает, без этого ничего подробнее не подскажу

Comment: Закиньте работающий и подгоним решение

Comment: я сейчас этим и занимаюсь, чутка позже скину. В любом случаи, спасибо)